# TWiki add new topic programmatically

Tags: twiki

How can I add a new topic to TWiki  programmatically?

I've got a working TWiki (http://twiki.org/) installation, everything works fine.

I need to find a way to create and add new Topics through the command line, programmatically.

Any ideas how this can be accomplished?

Thanx!

d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was

- take a look at some wiki pages (files in <twiki-home>/data/Main/<PageName>.txt) to figure out the file/text format (pretty much what you see in the browser, preceded by one line of meta info)
- generate that text format with a perl script 
   with content based on data from a DB or some Excel
- copy the files to the apropriate location using putty's pscp on windows

---

Comment: Very nice... and easy. One more file to change is .changes, which I need to append a single line with the topic, author, timestamp, and version. Thanx!

Comment: another thing I forgot to mention: beware of access rights to the file! My original copy was done with root => files were not visible in the webbrowser, since the httpd couldn't read/access them.

Answer (score 0):

I think using TWiki scripts is a more "clean" way, as you wouldn't have to worry about metadata in the TXT file or update the .changes file.

Just use wget to make a POST call using the 'save' script ([see documentation here](http://www.twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/TWiki/TWikiScripts#save))